# AWS SES PHP subject with question mark garbles email content

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

If I am sending an email via AWS SES with a subject over 45 characters and ending in a question mark (?) then the rest of the email returns code. I have the subject charset set to `UTF-8`.

**Email Subject**

`abghjkzqlkahjizalalalzcvzpozlkjzmrudiekzprioy?` - Breaks email
`abghjkzqlkahjizalalalzcvzpozlkjzmrudiekzprio?` - Works fine
`abghjkzqlkahjizalalalzcvzpozlkjzmrudiekzprioy!` - Works fine

**Email Content**

```
=?UTF-8?B?Pw==?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="----=_Part_1388091_1156038470.1487563296664"

------=_Part_1388091_1156038470.1487563296664
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.=
w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-=
microsoft-com:vml"><head><title>asdf</title><meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Typ=
e" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8"><meta name=3D"viewport" content=
=3D"width=3Ddevice-width"><style type=3D"text/css">=09=09=09body * {=09=09=
=09=09box-sizing: border-box;=09=09=09=09word-break: break-word;=09=09=09=
=09overflow-wrap: break-word;=09=09=09=09word-wrap: break-word;=09=09=09}=
=09=09=09body {=09=09=09=09padding: 0;=09=09=09=09margin: 0;=09=09=09=09bac=
kground: #FFFFFF;=09=09=09}=09=09=09#page {=09=09=09=09=.....
```

Comment: *How* are you sending this?  SMTP or with the API?  Using an SDK? Which version?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am sending it using the PHP SDK `sendEmail()` function - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-email-2010-12-01.html#sendemail